# Open DuckDB database using Python and DBeaver

Tags: python, sql, database, dbeaver, duckdb

I created a DuckDB file using the following Python code:

```
import duckdb
con = duckdb.connect(database=':memory:')
con = duckdb.connect(database='db.duckdb', read_only=False)
con.execute("CREATE TABLE items(item VARCHAR, value DECIMAL(10,2), count INTEGER)")
con.execute("INSERT INTO items VALUES ('jeans', 20.0, 1), ('hammer', 42.2, 2)")
# Testing
# con.execute("SELECT * FROM items")
# print(con.fetchall())
```

This creates the files:

```
db.duckdb
db.duckdb.wal
```

How can I run queries on these files using DBeaver? I am stuck creating the connection and don't understand what is required to connect.

[image]

Comment: what on the official web page https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/sql_editors/dbeaver did you not understand?

Comment: This describes how to set up a new database using DBeaver and DuckDB. My database already exists and was created with Python-Code.

Comment: @nbk In what way does your link relate to my question?

Comment: it tells you to add to path the file name and path  of your existing database

Comment: Got it. Saved the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above image set:

```
JDBC URL to: jdbc:duckdb:/home/<LOCAL_PATH>/db.duckdb
    Path to: /home/<LOCAL_PATH>/db.duckdb
```