# How to view DuckDB database in DBeaver?

Tags: database, dbeaver, duckdb

I created a DuckDB database in python and I'm getting:

```
con = duckdb.connect('../data/proposal.db')
con.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proposals")
>>>
┌──────────────┐
│ count_star() │
│    int64     │
├──────────────┤
│       200000 │
└──────────────┘
```

But once I setup a connection in DBeaver following the official docs here: https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/sql_editors/dbeaver,
connect to the same file as in python and run the same query

```
select count(*) from proposals
```

I get

```
SQL Error: java.sql.SQLException: Catalog Error: Table with name proposals does not exist!
Did you mean "temp.information_schema.tables"?
LINE 1: select count(*) from proposals
```

I also do not see any tables in the GUI browser for this database.

I have read a related question here:
[Open DuckDB database using Python and DBeaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73260618/open-duckdb-database-using-python-and-dbeaver)
but it talks about setting up a connection which I have already done

How can I visually explore a DuckDB database in DBeaver?

Comment: Sounds like you probably entered the path to the database incorrectly into dbeaver?